# Where can I find original Apple DOS 3.3 System Master diskette images?

Tags: apple-dos

The original Apple DOS 3.3 was [released on 1980-07-25](https://archive.org/stream/Beneath_Apple_DOS_OCR#page/n9/mode/1up), and there seem to have been at least [two more updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_DOS#Decline) after that that did not bump the version number:

> Two more versions of Apple DOS, both still called DOS 3.3 but with some bug fixes and better support for the new Apple IIe model, were released in early and mid-1983.

A [search for "DOS 3.3 system master" on `archive.org`](https://archive.org/search.php?query=dos+3.3+system+master) turns up a lot of different images, many with obvious modifications from the original, such as additional programs. Perhaps they also have less obvious modifications.

I'm looking for images of the original Apple DOS 3.3 System Master diskettes as distributed by Apple, with details about exactly which version each one is, and ideally with some effort made to confirm the provenance of the image. Where might I find such images?

Comment: First place I'd look is [asimov.net](https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/ftp.apple.asimov.net/images/masters/). They do have master images with a year in the name, so if you compare them, you may be able to figure out the version history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good start is always the collection of Apple related mirrors at https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/. Quite reliable and fast.

They include a copy of [ftp.apple.asimov.net](https://ftp.apple.asimov.net/) (slow), were the [1980 Master](https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/ftp.apple.asimov.net/images/masters/Apple%20DOS%203.3%20August%201980.dsk) can be found at [/images/masters/](https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/ftp.apple.asimov.net/images/masters/).

Apple.Asimov.Net is the semi official collection of all things Apple historical.